# Error SSL Protocol Erro: ERROR bad URI

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, ssl, curl, jekyll

I have the following remote Jekyll environment setup:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev make gcc
gem install jekyll bundler
sudo ufw allow 4000
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4000 -j ACCEPT
JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll serve --host "ip-address" --baseurl ""
```

* ip-addess is replaced with the real IP Address (hidden for privacy purposes).

When I try to serve the blog and access it, I get the following error on my browser(screenshot from Chrome. Same on Safari as well):
[image]
This is the server side error message:
[image]
However, everything works fine when I run curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with how Jekyll forces clients to connect over HTTPS without SSL certificates, resulting in browsers like Safari and Chrome not trusting the site.
I just had to make the following change in _config.yml file:

```
force-https: False
```